# Having issues accessing my cPanel url after deploying to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, cpanel

I encountered difficulties hosting a Next.js 13 application on cPanel, so I found a solution online that involved deploying the application on Vercel while configuring the DNS records in cPanel to point to Vercel for hosting. However, I'm currently experiencing an issue accessing cPanel via the URL 'www.example.com:2083,' which was not a problem when the website was built with React.js and directly hosted on cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Use your domain’s IP address.
Enter the IP address or domain and the 2083 service port in your preferred browser (for example, https://198.51.100.1:2083).

https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/accounts/how-to-log-in-to-your-server-or-account/